# android sdkmanager tool not found (flutter)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, flutter, android-sdk-manager

first post here hello everyone;

im trying to setup flutter without android studio in Ubuntu 19.10, but im having some problems to set up the android sdk:

```
Android sdkmanager tool not found (/home/mateo/tools/bin/sdkmanager).
```

my sdk is actually located in */home/mateo/tools/cmdline-tools/latest/bin*, how can i change the variable (or whatever it is) to point to the new location?

[this is what i get in the terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qqaW3.png)

i've already tried changing the following env variables, but the error is still there.

```
export ANDROID_SDK_HOME='/home/mateo/cmdline-tools/latest/bin/sdkmanager'
export ANDROID_HOME='/home/mateo/cmdline-tools/latest/bin/sdkmanager'
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

1. Go to Start Menu
2. Search for "Edit the system Environmental Variables"
3. Under the section "User Variables", create New Variable and name it "ANDROID_HOME"
4. And give the path of "ANDROID_HOME" to your new location. Use browse directory to set SDK location
5. Create another Variable named "ANDROID_SDK_HOME" and provide same path as previous one.
   That should do it

Comment: i forgot to say that im running ubuntu 19.1; but the equivalent process should do it, thanks a lot